# Requirements com.adobe.granite.xss not found on bundle start, but exposed

Tags: xss, aem, osgi-bundle

Since we migrate from CQ5.6.1 to AEM6.1 we have some difficulties to start our bundles :

```
17.08.2015 16:23:26.385 *ERROR* [qtp2140358820-67] org.apache.felix.http.jetty %bundles.pluginTitle: Cannot start (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.mybundle.core [477]: Unable to resolve 477.0: missing requirement [477.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.granite.xss)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.mybundle.core [477]: Unable to resolve 477.0: missing requirement [477.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.granite.xss)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
```

But when I look at the bundles console, under "Adobe Granite XSS Protection (com.day.cq.cq-xssprotection)" I see the right version exported :

```
Exported Packages   com.adobe.granite.xss,version=1.1.0
com.day.cq.xss,version=5.4.0
com.day.cq.xss.taglib,version=5.4.0
org.apache.sling.xss,version=1.0.0
```

The problem seems to be random (the exact same code and AEM version and java version works well on another pc)

Does anybody encountered the same issue ?

Comment: I see exported package version is 1.1.0 . Is "com.mybundle.core" has a dependency of the same version of "com.adobe.granite.xss" ?

Comment: You can check the version of dependencies in the Dependency Finder (http://<host>:<port>/system/console/depfinder) and make sure you are using the same version of the bundle in your code .

Comment: For com.adobe.granite.xss, the dependency finder gives me :

`<dependency>
 <groupId>com.adobe.granite</groupId>
 <artifactId>com.adobe.granite.xssprotection</artifactId>
 <version>5.5.62</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

It's exactly what I have in the parent pom.xml of com.mybundle.core